# make key function in AES algorithm in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, aes

I am new to encryption and decryption. I would like to generate keys for encryption and decryption like:

```
makeKey (byte[] k, int blockSize)(Android)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#import <Security/Security.h>

+ (NSData *)randomBytes:(size_t)count {
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:count];

    SecRandomCopyBytes( kSecRandomDefault,
                        data.length,
                        data.mutableBytes);
    return data;
}

NSData *key = [[self class] randomBytes: blockSize];
```

NSLog output:

```
key: <acbbc266 8a2a46ce 127e3e64 861795bd>
```

Comment: Also consider writing some explanation about what exactly your code is doing.. or what are you trying to explain.